# Validation of a set value with Reform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, reform, trailblazer

On attempting to extract the validation, I'm trying to use a Object Form, so, I found [reform](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform).

But I have a model with `enum` type. How can I validate this value on Reform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [reform documentation](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform/wiki/Rich-Validations) field can be validated with inclusion:

```
validates :status, inclusion: { in: %w(open closed) }
```